# ASP.Net MVC Resource Cannot be found error after upload on server

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I have used ajax calling to get details from database this ajax calling works fine in local but after uploading on server I always get error Resource Cannot be found I have tried many things depend on the solution on the web but no one succeed I even use to create details view and works fine on local but the same error after upload
i have tried

```
url: '/MobileS/Get/' + MobileSID
url: '~/MobileS/Get/' + MobileSID
url: '../MobileS/Get/' + MobileSID
```

and also i have tried despite its wrong but i think it may be work

```
 url: '../../MobileS/Get/' + MobileSID
 url: '~/~/MobileS/Get/' + MobileSID
 url: 'MobileS/Get/' + MobileSID
```

this is the main function

```
 function getbyID(MobileSID) {
        $('#Name').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');
  $.ajax({
            url: '/MobileS/Get/' + MobileSID,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            async: true,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                //var obj = JSON.parse(data)
                // alert(data);
                $('#Name').val(data.MobileSerial);
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            },
            error: function (errormessage) {
                alert(errormessage.responseText);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Can you include the action method code which returns `JsonResult`? Also `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` is pointless if you only pass single value.

Comment: [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Get(int id)
        {
            // return Json("Response from Get", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            DataAccessLayer db = new DataAccessLayer();
            var Serials = db.GetTbMobileSerial().Find(smodel => smodel.MobSerid == id);

            return Json(Serials , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }